# Keras multiple inputs masking

Tags: python, keras, lstm, masking, multiple-input

I am building a LSTM model with multiple inputs (the number is given by `n_inputs`). I scaled the inputs in `(0, 1)` and replaced all the `NaN` of the inputs with `-1`. Now I want the model to ignore such `NaN` values, therefore I use a mask as it follows:

```
model= Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=-1, input_shape=(window, n_inputs)))
model.add(LSTM(units=n_units), return_sequences=True)
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(LSTM(units=n_units))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
```

I am afraid that the `Masking` forces the model to completely ignore one timestep of data if any of the inputs has `NaN` value (I am not sure how to check if this is the case). What I want though is: for each timestemp, ignore only the `NaN` inputs, but pass the others that are valid.
My question is: does the `Masking` exclude all the timesteps for which at least one input is `NaN`? If it does, how can I get the model to ignore only the `NaN` inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so because I didn't know the answer and was curious about it, I made some experimentations. I first created a sequence made of 3 time steps and 3 features :

```
inputs = np.ones([1, 3, 3]).astype(np.float32)
```

and I created a simple network where I print two intermediary layers :

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,3))
mask=tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-np.inf)(inp)
out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,
                           kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Ones(),
                           use_bias=False)(mask)

model_mask=tf.keras.models.Model(inp,mask)
model=tf.keras.models.Model(inp,out)
print(model_mask(inputs))
print(model(inputs))
```

I used a Dense layer because it supports Masking and it allows to better understand what's happening, but the process is the same with RNNs. I also chose to set the mask value at -inf to see if the masked values are well masked. The weights of the Dense layer are set to one and I disabled biases, so this Dense layer calculate for each time step the sum of the inputs.

### **If i mask all the inputs of the time step :**

```
inputs[0, 2, :] = -np.inf
```

this is what i have :

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [nan nan nan]]], shape=(1, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 3.]
  [ 3.]
  [nan]]], shape=(1, 3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

So the mask was correctly taken into account.

### **If I want to mask one value** :

```
inputs[0, 2, 0] = -np.inf
```

and my outputs are :

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[  1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.]
  [-inf   1.   1.]]], shape=(1, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[  3.]
  [  3.]
  [-inf]]], shape=(1, 3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

So I conclude that masking was not processed.

### **You should create your own mask.**

I tried with a little exemple, so I hope this example is exploitable for your project. First, I forget the Vanilla [Masking](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking) layer from keras to use my own mask. The idea is to create a mask that put a 1 on masked values and 0 on real values. For instance, if your values are superior to 0, you replace your Nan values with -1 and you create your `custom_mask`:

```
inputs = np.array([[[1,2,1],[0.5,2,1],[1,0,3]]],dtype=np.float32)

inputs[:,1,0]=-1
inputs[:,2,2]=-1

custom_mask=inputs.copy()
custom_mask[inputs[:,:,:]>=0]=0
custom_mask[inputs[:,:,:]<0]=1
```

with `inputs` and `custom_mask` respectively :

```
[[[ 1.  2.  1.]
  [-1.  2.  1.]
  [ 1.  0. -1.]]]
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]]
```

Then, you mutilply your mask by `-1E9` in order to put infinite values where you want to mask your inputs. and you add it to your tensor. A simple `ReLu` set masked values to 0 :

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,3))
input_mask=tf.keras.activations.relu(inp-custom_mask*1E9)
out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,
                           kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Ones(),
                           use_bias=False)(input_mask)

model=tf.keras.models.Model(inp,out)
print(model(inputs))
```

equal to :

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[4.]
  [3.]
  [1.]]], shape=(1, 3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by creating a separable masking layer which acts on each channel independently.

```
import TensorFlow.keras.layers as tfl
class SeperableMaskingLayer(tfl.Layer):
def __init__(self, masking_value, time_steps) -> None:
    super(SeperableMaskingLayer, self).__init__()
    self.masking_layers = [tfl.Masking(mask_value=masking_value) for _ in range(time_steps)]
    self.squeeze = tfl.Lambda(lambda x: tf.squeeze(x, axis=1))

def call(self, inputs):
    outputs = []
    for i,x in enumerate(tf.split(inputs, num_or_size_splits=len(self.masking_layers), axis=1)):
        x = self.squeeze(x)
        outputs.append(self.masking_layers[i](x))
    return tf.stack(outputs, axis=1)
```